# SQL insert into..select + add column when there are multiple rows being added

Tags: sql, insert-into

I am trying to insert multiple rows into my `TherapistRates` table from my `serviceLink` table. I need to tack a `therapistID` onto each row. However, SQL is not allowing me to add a value when inserting multiple rows. How do I get around this?

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO TherapistRates (therapistID, serviceType)  
VALUES (@therapistID, (SELECT (serviceID) FROM serviceLink WHERE TherapistTypeID = @therapistID)
```

Comment: Seems odd to me that the type and the therapistID have the same value.  To resolve your issue simply move the @therapistID into the select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not:

```
insert into TheRapistRates (TherapistID, serviceType)
select TherapistTypeID , serviceID
from serviceLink
where TherapistTypeID = @TherapistID
```

NEW VERSION (from comment on other answers)

```
insert into TheRapistRates (TherapistID, serviceType)
select @TherapistID, serviceID
from serviceLink
where TherapistTypeID = @TherapistTypeID
```

Comment: Good pun with upper-casing specific letters in the table name.

Comment: because the serviceLink table doesn't have the therapistID column. its a value that must be passed in as a variable.

Comment: was a mistake Radu

Comment: @user2120280 Keep up, mate. Ninja edit to change it to TherapistTypeID, as per the WHERE matching it to the parameter

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Genuine mistake, but it's staying

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Insert  TherapistRates 
        (therapistID, serviceType)
Select  @TherapistId, ServiceId
From    ServiceLink
Where   TherapistTypeID = @TherapistTypeID
```

Comment: you would be right but i made a mistake when pasting! it should be

Comment: INSERT INTO TherapistRates (therapistID, serviceType) values

(@therapistID, (SELECT  (serviceID) from serviceLink WHERE TherapistTypeID = @therapistTypeID)

Comment: @user2120280 Updated.

Comment: perfect! thank you, Siyual. I wasn't aware i could do this as the serviceLink table does not include a column therapistID